Quasi-Newton method with constraints
I have an optimization process for an interior point method which, after solving for some additional variables, produces a Newton step of the form:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
H & A^t\\
A & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
dx \\ dy
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Note the linear constraint $A dx = 0$. Now the vector $dx$ is enormous, the matrix $H \succ 0$ is block diagonal with many blocks, and the vector $dy$ is much smaller (typically a few thousand elements).
The traditional way to solve this system is by substitution. The first equation produces $dx = H^{-1} (a - A^t dy)$ and then the second gives
\begin{equation}
C dy = A H^{-1} a, \qquad \text{with} \qquad C = A H^{-1} A^t.
\end{equation}
Unfortunately the matrix $C$, which is dense, takes a lot of time to form and invert. At the same time, I would really like to solve $A dx = 0$ exactly at every step. So here is my question: is there a quasi-Newton method like BFGS to approximate $C$ (or $C^{-1}$) but that ensures that $A dx = 0$?
Suppose that we approximate $C$ with some other matrix $D$, which for example is a low-rank update of the matrix used in the previous iterations (as in a BFGS-type approximation). Then substituting back produces:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
dy &= D^{-1} A H^{-1} a \qquad \Longrightarrow \\
dx &= H^{-1} (1 - A^t D^{-1} A H^{-1}) a \qquad \Longrightarrow \\
A dx &= (1 - C D^{-1} ) A H^{-1} a \overset{!}{=} 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
In some sense this last equation is a constraint on $D$, but of course we cannot solve it without knowing $C$ again...
Is there a standard operating procedure here? Perhaps one just adds an extra term to $dx$? If so, is there a canonical choice?
